# MPEG4 AVC header size?

Tags: mpeg-4, fuzzing

Just one question : what is the size in bytes of the header of a .mp4 file ?

The goal is to fuzz just this header.

Thanks
Karl

Comment: Please give more deatils if you need a more specific answer.

Comment: Its variable. You cant know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. ISO media container format (.mp4) uses a strusture of elements called **atoms**. It depends on the number of tracks, the H.264 encoding properties, the muxers also like to put their names in the file in a `free` atom.

Expect it to be at least 1 kByte. Anything over 4k is not very likely.

If you encounter the string `mdat` (header of the movie data atom), the file header is **probably** over.