# How much should I download from a mp4 to get it's metadata only

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to refresh metadata for large mp4 files in a database, I don't want to download the hole file to get the frame rate and resolution.

By experimentation I found that downloading only 1MB will suffice for `ffmpeg -i` to show me the info.

Can you point me to documentation that explains this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231566/4464702) answer points out that the MP4 file header size really depends on a number of factors, like:

- number of tracks
- the H.264 encoding properties
- some muxers put their names into remaining free space ("atoms" - see link above)

As stated in the linked answer, you can expect the header to be from **1 to 4 kBytes** large.

Since one megabyte is a comparably small amount of data nowadays (considering only a small amount of files - it may be different for you), you are very safe if you fetch the first megabyte only (1 MByte = 1024 KByte).

If you can stream the data you are getting and constantly check the bytes, you can listen for the character sequence `mdat`, as stated in the linked answer (again). It should denote that the file header is *probably* over.

Comment: This is a really bad way to do it. The real answer is to start download the file and parse it. The first 4 bytes of each atom are the type, the next 4 are the size. once you find an atom type of 'moov' the next 4 bytes tell you EXACTLY how many more byte to download.

Comment: @szatmary I mainly did a "link-only answer", but I also quoted the main parts of the link since it's the recommended way of doing it. I have pretty much next to no knowledge about the topic, and I stand corrected. Feel free to post a corrected version of my answer.